# Spacemacs: Error `Wrong type argument: commandp, org-set-tags` when setting tag

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I was not sure if this is a Spacemacs issue or a local configuration issue, hence I figured I would post to Emacs Stackexchange.

When I use the Spacemacs key `SPC-m :` to try and add a tag to an orgmode bullet point (or subtree heading), I get this error: `Wrong type argument: commandp, org-set-tags`. However, when I use the normal Orgmode key combination `C-c C-q` the tag will insert just fine.

I updated Spacemacs and the set of packages as well, but still getting the error. Not sure what would be causing this.

Comment: Do you see the problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. You can also set `debug-on-error` to non-nil to see a backtrace when the error is raised. That will show you what function is complaining about expecting a command but getting `org-set-tags` instead, what called that function, etc. Add such info to your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this error happens because the command `org-set-tags` has been renamed to `org-set-tags-command` in org-mode (which you can see in [this commit](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/4d152b994e889d09143b68fe3da9731d69087f2c)), but the keybinding hasn’t yet been updated in the master branch for Spacemacs.

On the develop branch, the binding has been updated to the new command, and moved to `SPC m i t`, which you can see [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/develop/layers/+emacs/org/packages.el) (currently it’s at line 325).

There is still a function called `org-set-tags`, but I think this error happens because it’s (not/no longer) meant to be called interactively (i.e. from a keybinding).

So, to fix this without updating to the develop branch, you can add the following code to your `.spacemacs` file (which you can edit using the command `spacemacs/find-dotfile`, normally bound to `SPC f e d`):

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  ;; Replace org-set-tags with org-set-tags-command in keybinding
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'org-mode ":" 'org-set-tags-command))
```

(At the recommendation of the [org layer docs](http://spacemacs.org/layers/+emacs/org/README.html#important-note), I’ve used `with-eval-after-load`.)

Comment: Oh thanks so much. Yes, I tried this and it seems to work now. I really appreciate it. I was having such a problem when the tags stopped working. Glad they are working again.

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Comment: I just pulled the latest Spacemacs (master), and this still hasn't made its way from develop. The fix presented here works great, though.